# Quickest way launch react native in expo

Tags: react-native, expo

Is their a quicker way to launch react native within expo or without epo possibly. I currently have to start up android studio, click on the emulator tab, `npm start` the project, then click `Run on Android device/emulator` twice one to launch the emulator, and one to load js bundles.

This process is quite a pain in the butt.

Ideally i would like to npm start the project, and the android emulator just opens, and boom im rocking and rolling.

I'm running on Mac Siera OS, what do you folks recommend the quickest way to get started using react native ?

Comment: you don't need to run android studio, unless you are changing native code.

Comment: then how would i get the emulator up and running ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

Comment: ^thx a bunch man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also create an alias.

```
emulator -list-avds # display a list of AVD names
alias android='/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/tools/emulator <NAMEOFDEVICE> -netspeed full -netdelay none &'

source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: enter this `alias android='/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/tools/emulator <NAMEOFDEVICE> -netspeed full -netdelay none &'` where ? terminal ?

Comment: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/make-an-alias-in-bash-shell-in-os-x-terminal/

Comment: change `NAMEOFDEVICE` to your device name.

Comment: after i have this set up, whats next ?

Comment: from your terminal run `android`

Comment: ok, im in my project directory and android gives me a list of options

Comment: `android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk`

Comment: thank for the help, but i think i will just stick with opening 2 terminal tabs one for `npm start` and on for `emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_28_x86`